# hotkey/shortcut for: "Which plugin is this?"

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, jface

Please forgive such a simple question, I've been away from RCP for about a year:

What shortcut/hot-key combination can I use in Eclipse to discover the plugin that contributed/owns the current view?

I remember it bringing up the plugin.xml of the plugin currently under the mouse.

I should be very grateful for your clues ..

M.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Plug-in Spy is mapped to <kbd>Shift+Alt+F1</kbd> (<kbd>Shift+Option+F1</kbd> on Mac) by default.  It shows information for whatever is currently selected.

Answer (score 4):

Best keyboard shortcut ever:  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>:  it displays all current keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Would you happen to know the Mac key combination for the same, Mark?

Comment: I'd guess "apple+shift+L", but that's just a guess.  It'll be whatever key you use with "c" and "v" to copy and paste... plus shift and L.