# How can I find source code for a "Plug-in Project" wizard?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

Using instructions in [Eclipse Source Code - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseCodeAccess/article.html), I can get the source code for all plugins. But how can I find in this enormous heap of text the code for one concrete wizard I really need? Namely, the wizard for plugin creation that has "Plug-in Project" menu item in "New" menu. The use of the search doesn't help. The search for "Plug-in Project" gives nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Plug-in Spy" says: `NewPluginProjectWizard` is contributed by 
`org.eclipse.pde.ui (3.6.100.v20120103_r372)`

Just open the dialog and press <kbd>Shift+Alt+F1</kbd>  (<kbd>Shift+Option+F1</kbd> on Mac)

See also: [hotkey/shortcut for: "Which plugin is this?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512113/hotkey-shortcut-for-which-plugin-is-this)

Comment: Thank you. That won't give me the java source yet, but I hope I could follow references to find it.

Comment: Try to install "Eclipse PDE SDK". That should contain all the necessary sources.

Comment: Thank you, I have installed ALL plugins already, with sources. Surely, the necessary source is here on my comp. Somewhere... :-)