# How to get java editor source code?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, pde

Where (if possible) can I get the source code of the java editor plugin.
I Ask this cause I am developing an IDE for Eclipse and I need to see how does Java editor handles the context information in content assist and others things.

Tks for your time,

Regards, Ramos

Answer (score 4):

Depending on which Eclipse package you downloaded you may already have the source. Look in `Help > About Eclipse` (`Eclipse > About Eclipse` on Macs) and click `Installation Details`. In the 'Installed Software' tab check for 'Eclipse SDK' - if you have this the source is installed.

If you don't have the source you can install it from the SDK update site for your Release - `http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.3` for Eclipse 4.3 (Kepler). Install `Eclipse SDK`.

Once you have the source installed go to `Preferences > Plug-in Development` and check the `Include all plug-ins from target in Java search` option (this is assuming you do not have a separate target platform). Once this is set searches for Java classes and menu options such as `Navigate > Open Type` will find classes in the Eclipse source as well as your source.

The Java editor is in the `org.eclipse.jdt.ui` plugin - `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitEditor`. Be warned that this is very complex code!

Comment: A very useful tool is the Plugin Spy. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4513693/639520